# Why is my SVG not showing as anti-aliased?

Tags: html, css, svg, antialiasing

No matter what I do, my logo won't anti-alias in my HTML page. This problem is annoying, and I can't seem to find any solution online at all. What is causing this to happen? The vector graphic shows normally when viewing it locally on Chrome, but the edges are jagged in the HTML. What gives?

HTML code:

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="img/logo.svg"></img>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```css
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  align-self: end;
}
```

Comment: share your svg code...

Comment: there, i just edited it.

Comment: share this zxcwhite.svg image or put your code in codepen and share

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed the issue, it's the way I exported it from my image editing application (Inkscape)